# Error in socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b", : cannot open the connection in Stan (from R)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rstan

I am on a Macbook Pro Retina Display from 2012 running El Capitan with 8 cores according to `parallel::detectCores()`.  My firewall is off.  I am performing the following call from `stan_lmer` loaded from the `rstanarm` package.

```
hierarchical.model.1 <- stan_lmer(y ~ x1 + (1 | x2) + (1 | x3) +
                            x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8,
                            data = df,
                            cores = NCORES, # NCORES = parallel::detectCores()
                            seed = SEED)
```

The exact error is:

```
starting worker pid=12968 on localhost:11058 at 23:51:49.107
Error in socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... doTryCatch -> recvData -> makeSOCKmaster -> socketConnection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  :
  localhost:11058 cannot be opened
Execution halted
  C-c C-c
```

Comment: I don't know why you are getting that error; it is known to work on newer Macs. If you set `NCORES` to 1, it should run successfully, albeit serially.

Comment: Right, but if I use one core, that defeats the entire purpose of parallelizing the MCMC.

Comment: I understand. Can you do any non-rstan example with `parallel::parLapplyLB`?

Comment: Like what?  I've never used that function before.

Comment: Like `example(parLapplyLB)`